# Why does my basic tcp chat application only work when connections are ended via ECONNRESET in nodejs?

Tags: c#, node.js, sockets, tcp

I have a weird scenario and I'm not sure how to solve it.

I have a simple tcp chat server in nodejs and my clients are currently in native C#, and eventually will move to Unity. I have my own networking library which creates the TCP connection and handles messages etc, and works fine in some cases until it comes to disconnecting.

The server is running on an EC2 instance and I am loading two windows on my PC to test the multiple connections. When I close the window, I receive this error in the nodejs server console

```
Error: read ECONNRESET
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:544:26)
```

Which is fine, because this is the scenario where it works. I'm guessing this just means that the connection was abruptly closed (closing the window).

However problems arise when I instruct the socket to be shutdown.

I am porting my client to Unity and when closing the client, it does not produce this `ECONNRESET` error and the connection never closes abruptly (like I'd expect it to), so in this case I have to manually close the connection on the client which results in a different error.

```
Error: This socket has been ended by the other party
    at Socket.writeAfterFIN [as write] (net.js:268:12)
    at /opt/chat/chat.js:32:10
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at broadcast (/opt/chat/chat.js:31:10)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/opt/chat/chat.js:26:2)
    at emitNone (events.js:72:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:166:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:905:12)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:441:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:17)
```

When I receive this error on the server, the other connected clients can continue messaging the server, however they cannot receive messages from it.

My nodejs server was pulled from github here:

https://gist.github.com/creationix/707146

```
// Load the TCP Library
net = require('net');

// Keep track of the chat clients
var clients = [];

// Start a TCP Server
net.createServer(function (socket) {

  // Identify this client
  socket.name = socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort 

  // Put this new client in the list
  clients.push(socket);

  // Send a nice welcome message and announce
  socket.write("Welcome " + socket.name + "\n");
  broadcast(socket.name + " joined the chat\n", socket);

  // Handle incoming messages from clients.
  socket.on('data', function (data) {
    broadcast(socket.name + "> " + data, socket);
  });

  // Remove the client from the list when it leaves
  socket.on('end', function () {
    clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);
    broadcast(socket.name + " left the chat.\n");
  });

  // Send a message to all clients
  function broadcast(message, sender) {
    clients.forEach(function (client) {
      // Don't want to send it to sender
      if (client === sender) return;
      client.write(message);
    });
    // Log it to the server output too
    process.stdout.write(message)
  }

}).listen(5000);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal of the server.
console.log("Chat server running at port 5000\n");
```

---

**Scenario**

Let's assume we have **CLIENT A** on the left and **CLIENT B** on the right

[image]

On initial connection, they can both chat fine.

**CLIENT B** wishes to disconnect, and the code forces the disconnect by terminating the socket. The nodejs server receives the error "This socket has been ended by the other party" and broadcasts that this player has disconnected to **CLIENT A**

[image]

**CLIENT A** wishes to continue communicating, regardless that no one is connected. **CLIENT A** continues typing and sending messages, however the messages are not being received once **CLIENT B** has disconnected. However, the messages are indeed being sent to the server.

**CLIENT A** is NOT receiving his own messages.

**CLIENT B** wishes to reconnect to continue chatting and does so.
**CLIENT A** sends message 'hello'
**CLIENT B** sends message 'hello'

[image]

**CLIENT B** is seeing both messages, and experiencing a normal chat, however **CLIENT A** is not seeing any of the messages and is stuck on a blocking call trying to read data.

---

This is ONLY when I force the socket closed, and it works perfectly fine when I receive the `ECONNRESET` error. How can I replicate this error, or fix my issue?

---

**EDIT**

I have managed to reproduce the `ECONNRESET` error and now it works, but it still doesn't explain why it doesn't work with other errors.

The methods `Close` and `GetStream().Close` in C# `TcpClient` are not sufficient it seems to close a connection properly. Instead I had to access the socket directly and close that.

Closing the socket directly works in a native C# application but not in Unity.

To replicate this error in Unity I have to use
`Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Receive);`